# Запятая в словосочетании

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в словосочетании "дворняга собака"?

Comment: Ответ зависит от контекста

Answer (score 1):

Надо бы дать полное предложение. Данное сочетание далеко не во всех конструкциях корректно, более распространено "собака дворняга" - здесь ничего не нужно, ни запятой, ни дефиса.

Дворняга, дворовая собака,..-обособленное распространённое приложение